# Boofuzz create nested blocks based on group values

Tags: fuzzing, boofuzz

In boofuzz, I'm trying to create nested s_block based on selected value from a s_group.

I'm getting two errors,
1) `BLOCK NAME ALREADY EXISTS: 1,` when I try to use two groups having same opcodes. I have a outer s_group containing possible opcode values ["1", "2", "3"] and inner s_group having possible values ["1", "2"]

2) I want use the value inside the s_block to depend on value selected in the s_group.

**The code I'm using is below:-**

```py
s_initialize(name="LOGIN-RQ")

with s_block("LOGIN"):
    s_group("Priority", ["1","2","3"])

    if(s_block_start("1", dep="Priority", dep_value="1", dep_compare="==")):
        # handle '1' - for A priority
        s_static("A")
        s_group("Type", ["1","2"])

        # handle '11 - for A priority Emergency'
        if(s_block_start("1", dep="Type", dep_value="1", dep_compare="==")):
            s_static("Emergency")
            s_static("#")
            s_string("1ab121-2345-2212-123ad21") # auth id
            s_static("#")
            s_static("Registered")
        s_block_end()

        if(s_block_start("2", dep_value="2", dep_compare="==")):
            s_static("Frequent")
        s_block_end()
    s_block_end()

    if(s_block_start("2", dep="Priority", dep_value="2", dep_compare="==")):
        s_static("B")
    s_block_end()

    if(s_block_start("3")):
        s_static("C")
        s_group("Category", ["1","2"])

        if(s_block_start("1", dep="Category", dep_value="1", dep_compare="==")):
            s_static("Anonymous")
            # handle anonymous category
        s_block_end()

        if(s_block_start("2", dep="Category", dep_value="2", dep_compare="==")):
            s_static("Registered")
        s_block_end()
    s_block_end()

session.connect(session.root, s_get("LOGIN-RQ"))
session.fuzz()
```

**Expected Possible Results:-**

```
1A1Emergency#1ab121-2345-2212-123ad21#Registered
1A2Frequent
2B
3C1Anonymous
3C2Registered
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

Yay!

Finally got it.

I had to update the block name & provide group names to those blocks, then everything started working. This code covers all the anticipated possible scenarios.

Posting the working code here, hope this will help be helpful

```
s_initialize(name="LOGIN-RQ")
with s_block("LOGIN"):
    s_group("Priority", ["1","2","3"])

    if(s_block_start("Priority1", group="Priority", dep="Priority", dep_value="1", dep_compare="==")):
        # handle '1' - for A priority
        #res = s_get_name_value('1')
        s_static("A")
        s_group("Type", ["1","2"])
        if s_block_start("Type1", group="Type", dep="Type", dep_value="1", dep_compare="==") :
                s_static("Emergency")
                s_static("#")
                s_static("1ab121-2345-2212-123ad21") # auth id
                s_static("#")
                s_static("Registered")
        s_block_end("1")

        if(s_block_start("Type2", group="Type", dep="Type", dep_value="2", dep_compare="==")):
            s_static("Frequent")
        s_block_end()
    s_block_end()

    if(s_block_start("Priority2", group="Priority", dep="Priority", dep_value="2", dep_compare="==")):
        s_static("B")
    s_block_end()

    if(s_block_start("Priority3", group="Priority", dep="Priority", dep_value="3", dep_compare="==")):
        s_static("C")
        s_group("Category", ["1","2"])

        if(s_block_start("Category1", group="Category", dep="Category", dep_value="1", dep_compare="==")):
            s_static("Anonymous")
            # handle anonymous category
        s_block_end()

        if(s_block_start("Category2", group="Category", dep="Category", dep_value="2", dep_compare="==")):
            s_static("Registered")
        s_block_end()
    s_block_end()

    if(s_block_start("Priority6", group="Priority", dep="Priority", dep_value="6", dep_compare="==")):
        s_static("NEVER")
    s_block_end()

session.connect(session.root, s_get("LOGIN-RQ"))
session.fuzz()
```

Comment: Glad you got it! Your name issue was due to the original code having two blocks named "1". Interesting that you needed to specify both `group` and `dep`; not sure why that is. One tip: You can declare blocks using the `with` statement to avoid needing to remmber the `s_block_end()` calls. E.g., `with s_block_start("Priority1", group="Priority", dep="Priority", dep_value="1", dep_compare="=="):`. Happy fuzzing!